# Post request Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, vue.js, post, vue-component

I have a custom multiple files upload using a VueJS [package](https://lian-yue.github.io/vue-upload-component/#/en), on front-end works fine and the post request is done, now the problem, I am not sure how to catch that post request to store files.

```
  <file-upload
    extensions="jpg,jpeg,png,pdf"
    :accept="accept"
    :multiple="true"
    :maximum="10"
    post-action="/upload/post"
    v-model="certifications"
    input-id="certifications"
    name="certifications[]"
    @input-filter="inputFilter"
    ref="upload">
  </file-upload>
```

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress development you should use "actions" or "filters" to hook into the correct place in code. A general good place is after "everything" is loaded but before output is made, and that is using `init` hook. Then you should check for POST and mitigate the file(s) upload.

```
<?php
// in a plugin.php or theme's functions.php:
function my_check_post() {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        $uploads_dir = '/uploads';
        foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
            if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
                $name = basename($_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key]);
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_check_post');
```

Comment: I get in this function, but also I get a 404  page not exist. Any idea how to get a 200 ?